# What spider is this

Tags: species-identification, zoology, arachnology

Live in London I have this in my backyard. Want to know what kind is it...Also does it bite? [image: backyard spider]

Comment: Please provide approximate size

Comment: May we get a view from the front? The eye pattern can be very helpful.

Comment: looks like a kind of wolf spider. legs not quite long enough for a dolomedes